# "I ask you consider" vs "I ask THAT you consider" vs "I ask you TO consider"

Tags: sentence-construction, infinitives

> 1. I ask you consider...
> 2. I ask **that** you consider...
> 3. I ask you **to** consider...

Which is correct?

Comment: The first one is incorrect; _ask_ does not take an infinitive without _to_. The next two are both correct; they are different structures but they mean the same thing. No real difference.

Comment: Assuming these are supposed to be "self-contained" questions (rather than just the first words within longer sentences), the standard phrasing would be *"I ask you to **reconsider**"*.

Answer (score 1):

*"I ask you to consider"* and *"I ask that you consider"* are correct. *"I ask you consider"* is incorrect without further context.

Depending on the rest of the sentence, you may want to rephrase it as *"Please consider..."*. Some example sentences:

"I ask that you consider your mother's feelings before you make a decision."
"Please consider your mother's feelings before you make a decision."
"I ask you to consider the consequences carefully before answering."
"Please consider my request for an extension."